# How to check connection in android studio

Tags: android

I want to create a submit button that previously checks the connection

Here is my code

```
btn_kirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (activeNetwork != null) {
                    // connected to the internet
                    if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        send();
                    } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        send();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

I found the code `NetworkInfo` `getActiveNetworkInfo()` `getType` `TYPE_WIFI` `TYPE_MOBILE` is deprecated
and when I try to run on virtual device the send button still execute

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a static method somewhere in your `AppUtils` class and add the code below in your class so you can use it everytime you want to check your connectivity.

```java
public final class AppUtils {
   public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = Objects.requireNonNull(cm).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }  
}
```

if you're going to use it in your activity you can remove the `static` keyword and define it as instance method(function) and call it everytime you want to use.

Inside your acitivty you can call it like this:

```java
        if (AppUtils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
            // do something when there is network
        } else {
            // tell user there is no internet connection and 
            // they should open data or connect to wifi
        }
```

And don't forget to add a permission in your android manifest.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: NetworkInfo, getActiveNetworkInfo(), isConnectedOrConnecting() is deprecated

my gradle
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: This works perfect on my machine. I have the same `buildToolsVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` as yours. You should probably invalidate your cache and rebuild your project or simply add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` on top of your method and it will run OK.